# SQL group by case statement with COUNT DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

My table in SQL Server 2012 looks like this:

```
SaleDate    CustomerID    Customer    
2014-03-01     NULL        George    
2014-03-01     NULL        John        
2014-03-01     125         Emy    
2014-04-01     126         Natasha    
2014-04-01     127         NULL   
2014-05-01     128         Jack
```

I want to find out the number of unique customers per sale date, considering that:

- there are cases when the *CustomerID* is missing (but the *Customer* name is known)
- and there are cases when *CustomerID* exists (but the *Customer* name is missing)

The desired output is:

```
SaleDate       UniqueCustomers
2014-03-01          3
2014-04-01          2
2014-05-01          1
```

I tried this query, but - of course - I get the following error: *Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause*:

```
SELECT SaleDate,
       CASE
           WHEN Customer IS NULL THEN COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID)
           ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT Customer)
       END AS "UniqueCustomers"
FROM TableA
GROUP BY SaleDate,
         CASE
             WHEN Customer IS NULL THEN COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID)
             ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT Customer)
         END
```

There is not a possibility to UPDATE the table to get rid of the NULL values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right way to do it. Use `Count` outside of `case statement`.

Considering that `CustomerID` is a `Integer` Column. Try this

```
SELECT SaleDate,
       Count(DISTINCT CASE
                        WHEN Customer IS NULL THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CustomerID)
                        ELSE Customer
                      END) AS UniqueCustomers
FROM   Yourtable
GROUP  BY SaleDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT PreparedTable.SaleDate, SUM(PreparedTable.Uniques)
FROM
    (
    SELECT SaleDate, COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) as Uniques
        FROM TableA
        GROUP BY SaleDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SaleDate, COUNT(DISTINCT Customer)
        FROM TableA
        WHERE CustomerID is null
        GROUP BY SaleDate
    ) PreparedTable

GROUP BY SaleDate
```